# Spring @Transactional configuring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

The rollback in my transaction doesn't work (Spring 3.1). I tried to edit my configuration xml file, like [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) but without result.
Here my xml file:

```
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:aop= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee   
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                ">
    
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceUsrAppe1" jndi-name="jdbc/ZhabDS"/>
        
        <bean id="utentiDAO" class="it.dao.UtentiDAO">
            <property name="dataSourceUsrAppe1">
                <ref bean="dataSourceUsrAppe1"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
<!--    doesn't work with this:
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
            <property name="dataSourceUsrAppe1">
                <ref bean="dataSourceUsrAppe1"/>
            </property>
        </bean>  
    </beans>
-->
</beans>
```

Should I add a transaction manager here?

Here's my service:

```
@Service
public class UtentiService {
    @Autowired
    private UtentiDAO utentiDAO;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class}, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean createUser(Zhabuten user)  throws Exception
    {
            long idPrincipale;
            idPrincipale = utentiDAO.insert(user, utentiDAO.query1);
            idPrincipale = utentiDAO.insert(user, utentiDAO.query2);

            if (idPrincipale!=0) throw new java.lang.Exception();

            idPrincipale = utentiDAO.insert(user, utentiDAO.query3);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The exception is correctly thrown, it's catched from the controller and the database is not rollbacked.
Do I missing any configuration in the xml?

Comment: Where does your transaction manager comes from?

Comment: have you checked the logs? Is the transaction starting and committing ?

Comment: I didn't understood how to configure it. Should do I remove this? <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
        <property name="dataSourceUsrAppe1">
            <ref bean="dataSourceUsrAppe1"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: I removed it, doesn't run on server, it gave me error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following xml configuration.

```
<!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceUsrAppe1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! 
Strangely after this I just got a new strange popup error from eclipse in debug mode (too after that I cleaned all olds breakpoints): Unable to install breakpoint it.service.UtentiService$$...CGLIB...$$someHEXnumber due to missing line compiler attributes. Modify compiler option to generate line number attributes.

Reason: Absent line number information.