# How to do transaction management without using @transactional annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a transaction manager bean in my `xml` as follows :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and session factory and data source beans as :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<!--   Hibernate SessionFactory -->

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

with session factory having all the `hbm` files mapping .

Now I have a `UserAddressManagerImpl` as follows :

```
public class UserAddressManagerImpl implements UserAddressManager{
 // methods to read and write in the database
}
```

and the bean for this is :

```
<bean id="userAddressManager"   class="com.sodiz.service.impl.UserAddressManagerImpl">
```

Now , this `UserAddressManagerImpl` doesn't have `@Transactional` on it .

Whenever I make any read operation from this class it works well but when making write operation it fails.

I am using this class packaged in a jar. So I prefer not to change this class.

So, is there any way to perform the read and write operations without using `@Transactional` annotations?

Comment: did you tried to use xml configuration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917842/spring-transactional-configuring-xml

Comment: Simplest way to put an annotation would be to create an empty subclass (or a decorator, or a wrapper, whatever suits your case) with @ Transactionnal at the top, and declare that new class in your application context.
That said, not sure what you mean by "reads work but writes fail", and not sure @ Transactionnal would help. Something deeper might be going on...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use aspects to achieve this without using the annotations:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userAddressManager" class="com.sodiz.service.impl.UserAddressManagerImpl"/>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
   <aop:pointcut id="userAddressManagerOperation" 
       expression="execution(* com.sodiz.service.impl.UserAddressManagerImpl.*(..))"/>
   <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userAddressManagerOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

Of course you could use more wilcards so that every service in your package applies to the above transactional settings.

Comment: I tried this solution after adding the pom dependancies . Now it is giving me an error of java.lang.VerifyError  . Falling of the end of the code.

Comment: make sure you have these defined in your beans tag: xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

Comment: I am already having  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
and xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" in my beans tag

Comment: add the stacktrace please

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/elcy/integration/custom/service/impl/jaxws_asm/ProcessIncomingFreeTextImportTransaction, method: getArg0 signature: ()Lcom/elcy/integration/custom/service/model/FreeTextImportTransaction;) Falling off the end of the code
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)

Comment: at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$4.run(ReflectionUtil.java:105)
  at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$4.run(ReflectionUtil.java:102)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
     at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredConstructor(ReflectionUtil.java:102)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.getValidClass(JAXBUtils.java:582) at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:309)     atorg.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.begin(JAXBContextInitializer.java:187)

Comment: check out this post.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror